# Wordpress Customizer inline css to css file

Tags: php, css, wordpress, inline

I am busy with the Customizer from WordPress and that is working fine i only getting the output of the css in the style tags (inline) and i want it in the customizer.css file.

Does somebody know how i can add the CSS into the customizer.css?

```
<?php
    function customizerCSS() {
        wp_enqueue_style('custom-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/customizer.css');

        $color = fw_get_db_customizer_option('body_background');

        $custom_css = '
                html, body {
                        background-color : ' . $color . ';
                }';
        wp_add_inline_style('custom-style', $custom_css );
    }
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'customizerCSS' );
 ?>
```

Comment: In your Backend go to: Design ⇒ Custom CSS and add your Stylesheet there.
Then it appears in custom.css

If you don't mean this way, please clarify your question.

Comment: @suther where is `Design ⇒ Custom CSS` in default wp installation?

Comment: you want to add css from `$custom_css` variable to `customizer.css` file?

Comment: I want $custom_css  getting outputed in customizer.css yes. Now i have just one value in it but it will be more so i dont want to get a whole inline CSS list included in the website.

Comment: @SamvelAleqsanyan, sorry had the wrong translation....  in English "design" is the Menu "Appearance": see: goo.gl/tkUGZL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) for getting all `css` written in the `customizer.css` file and [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) for adding new `css rules` into `customizer.css` file.

Your code will be:

```
function customizerCSS() {
    $color = fw_get_db_customizer_option('body_background');

    $custom_css = '
                html, body {
                        background-color : ' . $color . ';
                }';

    $file = file_get_contents(TEMPLATEPATH.'/customizer.css');

    if (strpos($file, $custom_css) === false) { // for not rewriting file every time, when there is no changes
        $file .= $custom_css;
        file_put_contents(TEMPLATEPATH.'/customizer.css', $file);
    }

    wp_enqueue_style('custom-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/customizer.css');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'customizerCSS' );
```

We are getting all new `css rules` from `$custom_css`, everything from `customizer.css` and comparing them. If there is new `css rules` in the `$custom_css` which aren't exists in the `customizer.css` stylesheet, then we just writе them into file.

**Edit:**

Function below will override `customizer.css` file with values from `$custom_css` variable every time:

```
function customizerCSS() {
    $color = fw_get_db_customizer_option('body_background');

    $custom_css = '
                html, body {
                        background-color : ' . $color . ';
                }';

    file_put_contents(TEMPLATEPATH.'/customizer.css', $custom_css);

    wp_enqueue_style('custom-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/customizer.css');
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'customizerCSS' );
```

Comment: glad to help you

Comment: Can i ask you still one question? the scripts add everytime the new value but dont remove the old one. How can i fix that?

Comment: your `$custom_css` everytime changes? or new css rules added to old `$custom_css` values?

Comment: The user can change the value. And when it is changed it's add the new value to the CSS file but dont overwrite/delete the old one. So now i have 3 times a html,body background color in the file. (Changed it 3 times)

Comment: yes, you're right. its a bit broad for me to understand what you want to achieve now. You have `customizer.css` with some css rules, then user add some css and you get it to `$custom_css` , then we split two rules into file `customizer.css`. you want to delete all css from file and keep only from `$custom_css`?

Comment: The user can change the values (now its only one value but this will be more) in the WordPress Customizer so when the user change some values the old ones needs to be overwriten by the new ones or maybe a other option is that the old ones will be removed in the file and the new ones will be added.

Comment: ok, there still one principal question: is it ok, if everytime we will delete all from `customizer.css` and add there rules only from `$custom_css` variable?

Comment: No thats no problem because there are no other values inside the file then from the $costum_css.

Comment: ok, then use code from updated answer. Your `customizer.css` file will contain only rules from last added `$custom_css`

Comment: feel free to ask questions, if they will be. you're welcome

Comment: any way to grab all css from customizer and put into the file?